# gcm register unsuccessfull in intentService?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I managed to register GCM to the server, I use the code below to do so ..

I put the code in activity ..

**1.  GcmMainActivity.java**

```
public class GcmMainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView lblMessage;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

    ConnectionDetector cd;
    public static String name;
    public static String email;
    public static String noHP;
    public static String pwd;
    private Dialog busyDialog; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        email = i.getStringExtra("email");
        noHP = i.getStringExtra("noHP");
        pwd = i.getStringExtra("pwd");

        // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

        // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

        // Get GCM registration id
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.              
                lblMessage.setText("account has registered"); //selanjutnya apa??
            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Register on our server
                        // On server creates a new user
                        Log.i("GcmMainActivity", "On server creates a new user");

                        GcmServerUtilities.register(context, name, email,pwd, noHP, regId,getString(R.string.alamatGcm));
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }       

    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());
            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            // Showing received message
            //registration success
            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };
}
```

with the above code I've tried to send a message and successfully

in docs I found

```
Note that Google may Periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your Android application with the understanding that the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent may be called multiple times. Your Android application needs to be Able to respond accordingly.
```

The application that I created has been able to handle it, I use almost the same code in another class, this is the code

**2. HbeatPullingService**

```
public class HbeatPullingService extends IntentService {
    public static final String ACTION_CONNECT = "com.ltvie.chatkrawala.ACTION_CONNECT";
    public static final String ACTION_SHUT_DOWN = "com.ltvie.chatkrawala.ACTION_SHUT_DOWN"; 
    public static int PULL_TIME = 150*1000; //2.5 minute
    static int ulang=0;
    String idanya;
    private JSONObject jObject;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private String regId;
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService", PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion",PROPERTY_REG_ID="registration_id";
    public HbeatPullingService(){
        this("HbeatPullingService");
    }
    public static Intent startIntent(Context context){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, HbeatPullingService.class);
        i.setAction(ACTION_CONNECT);
        return i;
    }
    public HbeatPullingService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "PullingService");
        wl.acquire();


                    jObject = new JSONObject(ret);
                    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
                                GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
                                GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
                                registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                                        DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));                           
                                    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                                        @Override
                                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                            // Register on our server
                                            // On server creates a new user
                                            Log.i("GcmMainActivity", "On server creates a new user");
                                            GcmServerUtilities.register(getApplicationContext(), "email", "name", "xxx", "00000", regId,getString(R.string.gcmAddres));
                                            return null;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                            mRegisterTask = null;
                                        }
                                    };
                                    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                                }
                                unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

    }
}
```

there is no error in the code and in the logcat says that the registration is successful ..

**3. logcat details.**

```
10-24 13:43:22.239: V/GCMRegistrar(5035): Is registered on server: true
10-24 13:43:22.239: I/GcmMainActivity(5035): On server creates a new user
10-24 13:43:22.259: I/AndroidGCM(5035): registering device (regId = APA91bHOk1aT-dLhTl8qUxNmSNyDCu5rfCdlx2lbM_w0zn92yLNqrGsDSZrd9TVujrwyhNYP_lfTnysDOIeqqY1IPRrWUPaSAJ4P2eJLzbwFrBCJlywnh_3pdQ3V9KfF4g4IHtvNK5kCZX938Ba15v3zcLGKuES2FA)
10-24 13:43:22.259: D/AndroidGCM(5035): Attempt #1 to register
10-24 13:43:22.259: V/AndroidGCM(5035): Posting 'noHP=00000&pwd=xxx&email=ltv@ltv.com&regId=APA91bHOk1aT-dLhTl8qUxNmSNyDCu5rfCdlx2lbM_w0zn92yLNqrGsDSZrd9TVujrwyhNYP_lfTnysDOIeqqY1IPRrWUPaSAJ4P2eJLzbwFrBCJlywnh_3pdQ3V9KfF4g4IHtvNK5kCZX938Ba15v3zcLGKuES2FA&name=lutfi' to http://example.com/gcm/register.php
10-24 13:43:22.939: V/GCMRegistrar(5035): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2014-10-31 13:43:22.935
```

But when I try to send a message I get

```
{"multicast_id":4745764600551626820,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

The registration means that I did not succeed, it had been 2 weeks I tried to find a solution but no solution, does affect the event? The first registration through the activity a success, but in HandleIntent unsuccessfull. please help.. 
thanks

Comment: Please check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542912/gcm-couldnt-receive-message/26543089#26543089

Comment: thanks. but that's not what I'm looking for..