# Using GCM, no error but no message received

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use GCM. I would like to send a message from a server (PHP file) to my device (Android phone)

The idea is to start the app, load test.php on any navigator (chrome, firefox...) and then a notification should appear on my phone.
Actually, nothing happen on my phone. In the log of Android Studio, I can see the GCM registration token, so it's ok for this. But after...I'm a little lost. How can I check the message is sent to server? How can I know the service is listening on app?

Here's my actual files, I have no error when I send the message and when I start the app:

test.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once __DIR__ . '/gcm.php';

$gcm = new GCM();

$data = array();
$data['message'] = "Un message de test";

// the topic you want to send notification
$topic = 'global';

// sending push message to a topic
$gcm->sendToTopic($topic, $data);

?>
```

gcm.php (I have removed the API key from here)

```
<?php
class GCM {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // sending push message to single user by gcm registration id
    public function send($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // Sending message to a topic by topic id
    public function sendToTopic($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => '/topics/' . $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // sending push message to multiple users by gcm registration ids
    public function sendMultiple($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    // function makes curl request to gcm servers
    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

        // include config

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=AIz...',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}}?>
```

And for the app:

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Registering BroadcastReceiver
        //registerReceiver();

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);

        }
...
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

RegistrationIntentService.java

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);


            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            subscribeTopics(token);
      sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);

            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]

}
```

MyGcmListenerService.java

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

build.gradle (google-services.json is generated and is in "app" folder)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Google Play Services
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and finally the manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <service
            android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question with specifics of what is wrong with your current code and what you expect to be happening.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the status of messages sent via GCM is now available for published Google Play apps using [GCM statistics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en). To see GCM statistics on your Google Play Developer Console, associate the GCM Simple API Key or C2DM token with your application by the following steps:

> 1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. On the left menu, click **Services & APIs**.
> 4. Click the **Link a sender ID** button.
> 5. Type your GCM API key or C2DM client login token.
> 6. Click **Link**.

Once your app is published, you can view GCM statistics on your app's **Statistics** page.

> 1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. On the left menu, click **Statistics**.
> 4. Next to "Statistics," click the drop-down and select **GCM statistics**.

And for your coding problem, this SO post - [GCM couldnt receive message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542912/gcm-couldnt-receive-message?rq=1) can help.